# Why does rendering of `plotly` line chart with stair case model is slow

Tags: r, plotly

I have `plotly` graph inside a `shiny` App. Here the `plotly` graph shows three data; two of the them as lines and  one of them as markers.
For the line graph, its in **stair case** model due to requirements.
The data I use has **65,000 rows** but on plotting there's a noticeable lag. As a result, it becomes hard to use zoom and other functionalities.

Sample Data:

```
library(dplyr)
library(lubridate)

now <- now()
num_rows <- 65000

timestamps1 <- seq(from =  now, by = seconds(6), length.out = num_rows)
values1 <- runif(num_rows, min = 100, max = 300)
one <- data.frame(Timestamp = timestamps1, Value = values1)

num_rows <- 4330
timestamps2 <- seq(from = now , by = seconds(900), length.out = num_rows)
values2 <- runif(num_rows, min = 100, max = 300)
one_ui <- data.frame(Timestamp = timestamps2, Value = values2)
```

Here's the `plotly` code:

```
library(plotly)
plot_ly() %>%
          add_trace(
            data = one, x = ~Timestamp, y = ~Value, name = "Raw Data", mode = "lines", type = "scatter",
            line = list(color = "#f69a8e", shape = "vh"),
            hovertemplate = "Timestamp:%{x}<br>Value:%{y:.2f}"
          ) %>%
          add_trace(
            data = one_ui, x = ~Timestamp, y = ~Value, name = "Reg Data", type = "scatter", mode = "lines", line = list(color = "#6bbcf3", width = 4, shape = "vh"),
            hovertemplate = "Timestamp:%{x}<br>Value:%{y:.2f}"
          ) %>%
          add_trace(data = one_ui, x = ~Timestamp, y = ~Value, name = "Reg Data points", type = "scatter", mode = "markers", marker = list(color = "#0788DE", width = 2), visible = "legendonly") %>%
          layout(
            xaxis = list(title = "Time Stamp (UTC)"),
            yaxis = list(title = input$drop_down)
          )
```

When `shape = "linear"`, overall functionalities in graph become smooth.
Tried with `ggplot` as well but similar lag is obtained by using `geom_step()`.

Is it possible to render `plotly` graph without any lag or should I down sample or do I need to make any changes in the Shiny App.

Comment: try `plotly::toWebGL()`

Comment: Tried it but not much of difference. `layout(
            xaxis = list(title = "Time Stamp (UTC)"), yaxis = list(title = input$drop_down) )%>% toWebGL()`
Is this the way to do it